# Python regex if group-match then put-different-character

Tags: python, regex

I wish to transform the following:

> "some text **http://one.two.three.source.com** more text.    more text
>   more text **http://source.com** more text. more    text
>   **http://one.source.com** more text more text. more    text **http://one.two.source.com** more text more text"

To this:

> "some text **http://one_two_three.target.com** more text    more text
>   more text **http://target.com** more text more    text
>   **http://one.target.com** more text more text more    text **http://one_two.target.com** more text more text"

I wish to transform '.' separating each subdomain to '_' in a large chunk of text, the problem is that I want to make it conditional to whether there are subdomains or not. 
I cannot predict the rest of the text and the transformation need to occur only for url patterns.

This is what I have so far:

```
src = 'source.com'
dst = 'target.com'
reMatch = r'http(?P<a>s?):(?P<b>\\?)/(?P<c>\\?)/(?P<d>([^.:/]+\.)?)(?P<e>([^.:/]+\.)?)(?P<f>([^.:/]+\.)?)' + src
p = re.compile(reMatch, re.IGNORECASE)
reReplace = r'http\g<a>:\g<b>/\g<c>/\g<d>\g<e>\g<f>' + dst
p.sub(reReplace, content)
```

It only replaces 'source.com' with 'target.com' and copies the subdomains (up to 3) but do not replace '.' with '_' between subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a function that achieves your desired output given your input:

```
def special_replace(s):
    p=re.compile(r"(http://.*?)(\.?source\.com)")
    spl=p.split(s)
    newtext=[]
    for text in spl:
        if text.startswith("http://"):
            text=text.replace(".","_")
        elif text.endswith("source.com"):
            text=text.replace("source.com", "target.com")
        newtext.append(text)
    return "".join(newtext)
```

It's not that elegant but it reaches your goal :).

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of halex's answer. `grouper` from [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) is useful in processing the results of `re.split`.

```
def special_replace(s):
    spl = re.split(r"(http://.*?)(\.?source\.com)", s)
    return "".join(
        itertools.chain(*((
                  text,
                  part1.replace(".", "_"),
                  part2.replace("source.com", "target.com"))
              for text, part1, part2 in grouper(3, spl, ""))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is that you are applying two distinct changes to your matched expression. I suggest you apply one of the changes throughout your file and then match against this new expression in order to reconstruct it using captured groups:

```
text = re.sub(r'(http://[^ ]*)source\.com\b', r'\1target.com', text)
pattern = re.compile(r'(http://[^ ]+)\.([^ ]*target.com)\b')

while (pattern.search(text)):
   text = pattern.sub(r'\1_\2', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is where using functions as replacements will fit in nicely:

```
def replace_dots(source):
    from_dot_com = 'source.com'
    to_dot_com = 'target.com'

    pat = re.compile(r'(https?://)(\S*?)(\.?)'
                     + re.escape(from_dot_com),
                        re.IGNORECASE)

    def my_fun(match):
        return (match.group(1) 
            + match.group(2).replace('.', '_') # <--
            + match.group(3) + to_dot_com)

    result = pat.sub(my_fun, source)

    return result
```